# How to disable or hide "Today" button for angularui-datepicker based on condition if its weekend

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

How to hide/disable "Today" button based on condition. Let's say if today is weekend. I want to hide "Today" button.

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group datePicker">
              <input id="dt-date" name="dt-date" class="form-control"
                type="text" size="10" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default'}"
                required required-err-message="Date is Required"
                uib-datepicker-popup="{{TestVm.datePickerFormat}}"
                ng-model="TestVm.date"
                is-open="TestVm.dateDatePicker.isOpen"
                datepicker-options="TestVm.datePickerOptions"
                close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="TestVm.datePickerAltInputFormats" />

                <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button type="button" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default'}" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="TestVm.dateDatePicker()">
                   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                   </button>
                </span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Datepicker options in Angular Controller

```
TestVm.datePickerOptions = {
                formatYear: 'yy',
                startingDay: 1,
                showWeeks: false,
                dateDisabled: myDisabledDates
            };
```

Function which disables weekends

```
function myDisabledDates(dateAndMode) {

        return (dateAndMode.mode === 'day' && (dateAndMode.date.getDay() === 0 || dateAndMode.date.getDay() === 6)) ;
    }
```

Datepicker Image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The dateDisabled is used to disable the dates in the calendar so you cannot click on them, not to hide the Today button. If you wish to hide the Today button you are going to have to override the template used to display the calendar and give the Today button an ID so that you can reference it and hide it.
From the uid-datepicker documentation

> template-url (Default: uib/template/datepicker/datepicker.html) - Add
>   the ability to override the template used on the component.

You should copy that template and give it your own name and then reference that. In the template, give the Today button an ID, e.g. ID="myTodayButton".
You will then need to write a function that gets the current day and if it is a weekend then disable or hide the myTodayButton.